# NullPointerException in bean injected in Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I have two servlets: ServletUtils and ServletAditional.
ServletAditional uses a method from ServletUtils called isAllowed to check whether the user can access the webpage or not. The problem is that every time ServletAditional tries to use this method ends in a NullPointer exception caused by the bean UserCalculation, which is null.
After having a quick look a the servlet in debug mode, I found that the init method in ServletUtils is never called. I tried to set the bean at login and even forcing the init in the Login init, but the bean is still null.
My question is, is there a way to initialize ServletUtils and set the bean without having to re write every servlet?

ServletUtils:

```
public class ServletUtils extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HttpServletRequest request; 
private HttpServletResponse response;
private UserCalculation userCalculation;
protected User user;

public void setUserCalculation(UserCalculation userCalculation) {
    this.userCalculation = userCalculation;
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException {
    //does nothing, not necessary
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //does nothing, not necessary
}

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
    this.userCalculation = (UserCalculation) ctx.getBean("UserCalculation");
}

public boolean isAllowed(int idRole) throws ServletException, IOException{
    User user=(User) getSessionAttribute("user");
    return userCalculation.checkRole(user, idRole);
}
}
```

ServletAditional:

```
public class ServletAdicional extends ServletUtils {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int role=1;
private AditionalService service;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    setRequestResponse(request, response);

    if (!isLogedIn()){
        redirectLogin();
    }
    else if (isAllowed(role)){
        setDefaultAttributes();
        redirectTo("CalculateAditionals");
    }
    else{
        redirectToErrorPage();
    }
}
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
    this.service = (AditionalService) ctx.getBean("AditionalService");
}
}
```

Error message says:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [aditionalReport] in context with path [/ElectronicaProject] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at electronicaProject.servlets.ServletUtils.isAllowed(ServletUtils.java:82)
    at electronicaProject.servlets.ServletAditional.doGet(ServletAditional.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. As you have overridden `init()` method in both the classes hence `init()` method of `ServletUtils` is never called and `userCalculation` is never initialized.

Read more about

- [Oracle Java Tutorial - Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)
- [Oracle Java Tutorial - Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

---

Try

```
public class ServletAdicional extends ServletUtils {
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        super.init(config);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Let's have a look at simple program to understand it.

```
interface Init {
    public void init();
}

class ServletUtils implements Init {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("inside ServletUtils's init method");
    }
}

class ServletAdicional extends ServletUtils {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("inside ServletAdicional's init method");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    Init init = new ServletAdicional();
    init.init();
}
```

output:

```
inside ServletAdicional's init method
```

---

#### Some Points:

- Call `super.init(config);` in `ServletUtils` class as well.
- Try to avoid instance members in Servlet such as `user` if it's not a singleton because it's treated as shared object for multiple requests to the Servlet.
- If you don't want to provide any implementation they don't override these methods.
- Don't make `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` as instance members of the Servlet if needed then simply pass it as method arguments.

Comment: And don't hand-write servlets in the first place.

Comment: @Braj thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that. Must get some sleep.Unfortunately that's the point of this entire project.